# Overcoming Space Character error in Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java

I am trying to launch command prompt via a Java application and then run a bat file in a specific file path. The "Runtime.getRuntime().exec" does not accept spaces in the file path. I am aware that this can be contained by following option,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"D:\\Test\\Spaced Folder\\start.bat");
```

However, in my case I have used a filepath String that I have captured from a textbox. So, I have used the below syntax,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+Filename+"\\start.bat");
```

In this case I still get the error that "Windows cannot find 'D:\Test\Spaced'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again."

Could you please let me know how can I overcome the space character incompatibility when I am using a String reference in Runtime.getRuntime().exec and if that String has spaces in it.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote path:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \""+Filename+"\\start.bat\"");
```